# Sharing folders between alfresco instances?

Tags: alfresco

Is it possible to have multiple Alfresco instances sharing one common folder in the repository tree? How to set this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alfresco doesn't allow for folders being shared in the way you are asking. You can share the whole repository with multiple instances, which would be a [cluster configuration](http://www.slideshare.net/alfresco/06192008-high-availability-clustering-with-alfresco).

Since version 3.4 Alfresco has a [Replication Service](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Replication_Service) that you can use to replicate a folder structure from one repository to another. Currently there is not much of a user interface for the Replication Service and it is a really new feature, so I'm not sure if it'll work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that you are asking for something different, but maybe this helps : if you deploy you alfresco.war on an application server, you can define the location of the repository by setting the **dir.root** attribute in the **alfresco-global.properties** file. If you are using JBoss, this file can be found or created under **...server/${your.server(probably default)}/conf**. I am not sure though if sharing a whole repository is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post:

http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=37408&p=109230&hilit=target+remote#p109230

It might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The Replication Service, which was new in Alfresco 3.4, should deliver what you need for this. The two main wiki pages to read up on this would probably be:

- http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Community_3.4.a#Replication
- http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Replication_Service
- http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Transfer_Service (The replication service is built on top of the transfer service, so some of the information and diagrams could be of interest)

(There's also a page on the http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Replication_REST_API if you're interested.)

As an Administrator, if you log into Share then under More / Tools you'll find the "Replication Jobs" entry. In here, you can create replication definitions to send a part of your repository to another server. You can also schedule it, so that eg it'll be replicated every day, or you can run it as a one off.

Before you can configure replication to a destination server, you'll need to create a transfer target definition for that server. Details are in the online help:
http://www.alfresco.com/help/34/community/sharehelp/tasks/adminconsole-replication-create.html . The online help also covers quite a few more bits of the replication UI, so it's worth a read - look under "Share Admin Console" then "Managing Replication Jobs"